# Finding linear projection $L(y\mid 1,x)$ when $E(y\mid x) = \alpha + \beta_1 (x-\mu) + \beta_2(x-\mu)^2$ with $\mu = E(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, conditional-expectation

In addition to what's stated in the title, assume that $x$ has a symmetric distribution, so that $E[(x-\mu)^3]=0$.

So the full question is:

> How can I find the linear projection, $L(y\mid 1,x)$ when $E(y\mid x)
>  = \alpha + \beta_1 (x-\mu) + \beta_2(x-\mu)^2$ with $\mu = E(x)$, and where $x$ has a symmetric distribution?

I don't really know how to approach this. I believe the first two terms are easy (but perhaps I'm wrong because I'm just using intuition here), 
$$
L(y\vert 1,x) = (\alpha -\mu) + \beta_1 x
$$
because these are linear and in the span of $x$.

I'm not sure how to handle the third term though; I've been trying to use some clever multiplication or iteration to turn it into a $(x-\mu)^3$ term, but that messes up the other two terms. Plus, even if I get it to $(x-\mu)^3$, I don't know where I'd get an *unconditional* expectation from (I can get a conditional expectation from iteration properties of linear projection and conditional expectation).

In this case I'd prefer a hint over an answer, if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: You just need to identify the linear projection of $(x-\mu)^2$, since everything else is already in the linear span of $x,1$. Noting that $x-\mu$ and $1$ are orthogonal, this is quite easy.

Comment: @zhoraster Sorry, but I know very little about linear projections. $(x-\mu)^2$ is orthogonal to $1$, yes. But I don't know how that helps me.  
If I try to approach intuitively. I think the $(x-\mu)$ orthogonal to $1$ means that the linear projection of $(x-\mu)^2$ onto $span(1,x)$ is of the form $a\cdot x$? Therefore it will be the linear projection of $x^2-2x\mu$ onto $x$? And then I think this final linear projection is $x-2\mu$?

Comment: No, not correct. Here a hint for you: if $V = \operatorname{span}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k)$, where $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$ are orthogonal, then the projection of $x$ on $V$ is $$\operatorname{pr}_V x = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(x,x_i)}{|x_i|^2} x_i.$$

Comment: @zhoraster When I apply that formula where $V=span(1,x)$, I get a result that I feel is incorrect. Specifically, I get $$\frac{(x-\mu)^2.1}{1}1 + \frac{(x-\mu)^2.x}{x.x}x$$ which is $2(x-\mu)^2$  since here everything are scalars.  
Firstly, projecting scalars onto scalars doesn't make sense to me. Thus I want to solve the problem taking $y,x$ as vectors, if possible. However, if I take them as vectors I get confused because then how can we do dot product between $(x-\mu)^2$ and $x$? Because if we take "^2" to mean dot product, then $(x-\mu)^2$ is scalar and $x$ is vector.

Comment: and if instead we take $(x-\mu)^2$ to mean $(x-\mu)(x-\mu)'$, then this is a (square) matrix (if vectors are column vectors) and similarly, dot product between matrix and vector doesn't make sense to me (if it is defined? I do not know).
**To Summarize**, If I take $x,y$ to be scalars I get result I feel is incorrect (and projecting scalar on scalar to me doesn't make sense). if I treat them as vectors I don't think the dot product makes sense.
**Perhaps** I am using the wrong dot product (inner product)?. Either that or I am not understanding something simple and fundamental.

Comment: 1. The inner product now is $x.y = E[xy]$. 2. In order to use my hint, note that $\operatorname{span}(1,x) = \operatorname{span}(1,x-\mu) $.

Comment: @zhoraster Aha! Now things make more sense.then we have the projection of $(x-\mu)^2$ onto $(1,x)$ is the projection of $(x-\mu)^2$ onto $(1,x-\mu)$. This is $$\frac{E[(x-\mu)^21]}{1}1 + \frac{E[(x-\mu)^3]}{(x-\mu)^2}(x-\mu) = var(X)+0 $$!
**I am now just wondering then** why $span(1,x)=span(1,x-\mu)$? Is it just because, for any vector $v=a_{1}1 + a_2 x = (a_1+\mu)1 + a_2 (x-\mu)$ and vice versa? That is, we can re-write any vector in the $span(1,x)$ in terms of $(1,(x-\mu))$ and vice versa? Or is it perhaps because $1 and (x-\mu)$ are orthogonal?

Comment: Yes, this is correct (except the last question).

Comment: @zhoraster Alright. Thank you very much! You answered all my questions and I really appreciate the help.

One thing to note: The question has a bounty on it, and while I haven't done a bounty in a while, I don't think I can award it to you unless you actually post an answer. Thus, if you want the bounty feel free to post an answer before it expires and I'll award it to you. If not, I'll try to post an answer sometime and the bounty will just expire. Thanks again!